# How to pass $_FILES from Perl to PHP

Tags: perl, libcurl

I have to interact with a PHP script that receives file uploads using a form. Looking at the code it loops through an array called $_FILES. I need to be able to post to this form using Perl and would like to ask what would be the best way to pass the file names ? Would I use something like WWW:Mechanize ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your question is:

> How do I simulate submitting a form (with a file input) using Perl?

The fact that it is handled with PHP on the backend is irrelevant to the problem.

Note that you need to submit **actual files** not file names.

WWW::Mechanize is an option, I'd probably use [LWP::UserAgent](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) myself, it makes use of [HTTP::Request::Common](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon) which allows you to select files to upload by passing an arrayref instead of a string.

```
[ name  => 'Gisle Aas',
  email => 'gisle@aas.no',
  gender => 'M',
  born   => '1964',
  init   => ["$ENV{HOME}/.profile"],
]
```

Answer (score -1):

https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::Interpreter#TYPE-HANDLING

Quick google search, allows PHP and Perl code to interact with one another.